# Phonegap Push Example Returning Bad Gateway

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm trying to use the standard tutorial from the Phonegap tutorial here: http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/push-notifications/

I've got to "Sending Your First Push", trying to send to my Android device.

```
phonegap push --deviceID APA91bE1MmeTc92igNoi5OkDWUV --service fcm --payload "{ \"data\": { \"title\": \"Hello\", \"message\": \"World\"} }"
```

I replaced device ID with the ID that you get from the registration event/Device Push ID. I get the following error:

```
body: <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

According to this I should just try later, but I've been trying this over multiple days:
[GCM push notifications cause 502 Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060968/gcm-push-notifications-cause-502-bad-gateway)

Is Phonegap missing something basic here that I should know, or does the tutorial simply not work? If it doesn't work, are there any plugin suggestions to get the push notifications quickly up and running?